# Swift - extend an enum for only one of its cases

Tags: swift, enums, where-clause

So I have an enum that controls an instance of a view controller as well as the creation of said view controller. See below:

```
enum RGOSessionsTableType {
    case Active
    case Scheduled
    case Finished

    func instantiateViewController() -> RGOSessionsTableViewController {
        var id = ""
        switch self {
        case .Active: id = "ActiveSessionsTVC"
        case .Scheduled: id = "ScheduledSessionsTVC"
        case .Finished: id = "FinishedSessionsTVC"
        }
        return UIStoryboard(name: "MainView", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(id) as! RGOSessionsTableViewController
    }
}
```

I want to create a property on that enum that stores the instantiated view controller, however for reasons I won't explain (mainly ease of integration with existing code), I wish to use the specific class types for Active, Scheduled and Finished respectively. They all inheirit from `RGOSessionsViewController` but as I mentioned I would rather  not make the property of this lower level type.

I have tried the following which will not compile, I have never done where clauses on extensions before so it is likely I have the syntax wrong, that or it simply isnt possible:

```
extension RGOSessionsTableType where self == .Active {

}
```

Any and all suggestions appreciated.

Comment: I think here enum is not a best idea. You should try to do this with protocol + 3 classes/structs implementing it. That will allow you both extend "only one case" and add more "cases" in it. Like that: https://medium.com/@rjchatfield/the-expression-problem-in-swift-6f2471291604#.rxvyopinn

Comment: Turns out that what I'm trying to do isn't possible anyway because `RGOSessionsTableType` is not a generic type. Your suggestion was infact the way to go, feel free to submit it as an answer, including why my proposed solution wasn't possible and I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moved from comments:

> I think here enum is not a best idea. You should try to do this with protocol + 3 classes/structs implementing it. That will allow you both extend "only one case" and add more "cases" in it. Like [here](https://medium.com/@rjchatfield/the-expression-problem-in-swift-6f2471291604#.rxvyopinn).

Quick info about linked article:

> ## Why I don’t love Swift Enums any more
>
> At the last two Sydney Cocoaheads, any time I see a use of Enums in a talk, I make sure to ask “Why an enum and not a protocol?”. This blog post will hopefully explain the smell of enums.
>
> ---
>
> Firstly, I have to say that enums are great if you never need to extend the number of cases. However, incorrect usages of enums break the **O** in **SOLID** Principles.
>
> #### Open Close Principle
>
> *A Type should be open to extension, but closed for edits.*
>
> And I believe the Expression Problem best explains the violation.
>
> #### The Expression Problem
>
> *Add new methods; add new cases. Pick one.*
>
> I will attempt to walk you through the Expression Problem with enums, then proceed to “solve” it with the Visitor Pattern.